# LibreOffice: Cells with text to date

Tags: date, type-conversion, libreoffice-calc

I have loaded an xlsx file where the original author used Microsoft Office to create the file. In the spreadsheet, there is a column of dates given in format like "DD/MM/YYYY TT:MM:SS", but they are stored as text. Furhteron, "DD/MM/YYYY TT:MM:SS" is not locale default. I cannot find a way to make LibreOffice interpret it as date. Can someone please help me to reach my aim?

Comment: Obviously, my post gets downvoted, maybe it does not require research. It is just interesting that I am googling since 2 hours and could bunch my head because nothing I've found until now I tried and did not work.

Comment: How is the value stored/visible in the cell in libreoffice? Do you see a single quote before the value? Furthermore, what have you tried until now? Did you try the usual methods, like "multiplying by one", or `DATEVALUE()` or with a "`CONCATENATE()` / `TEXT()`" combination?

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the column of dates.  From the menu, select Data -> Text to columns.  In the dialog window that pops up, press "OK".  That should do it.